# Importing / Using Volley for Android trouble

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm importing Volley using Gradle, more precisely:

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.15'
```

(I know it's an unofficial mirror).

My trouble is: in this mode Volley is downloaded every time that APP starts or only when I compile for debugging / distribuiting? Just worried about an offline site or so...

Another thing: every tutorial that I did read on internet say to add Volley at startup of the APP, adding in manifest.

1) I did understand that in this manner I can get a Class from every point of my APP (Singleton)... is it right?

2) Is it possible add multipe classes in same mode, adding to manifest?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
   compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
```

and then use this as a library , you can customize it how ever you want to use it.
I can see you using "aar" of it.

Let me come to your points

```
First Doubt:
```

Volley is downloaded every time that APP starts or only when I compile for debugging / distribuiting? Just worried about an offline site or so...

```
Answer
```

Volley is downloaded only once you give its dependency in build.gridle file.
So Don't worry and VOlley is used to make server calls so i don't think it make any sense with offline site.

1. After adding a dependency you can get access to volley methods in whole application.
2. Didn't understand the question. As manifest is the the one where you add this dependency. :P

Enjoy !!

Comment: OK, thank you, but could you give me an answer to my questions? Thank you ;)